# Eclipse neon JSDT issue

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I tried the following basic steps.

Have a brand new eclipse neon installation, new workspace, not old .eclipse settings.

Start a plain empty JavaScript project with a simple function and type "window. + CTRL-SPACE".

This doesn't bring up any autocompletion like window.confirm or window.alert

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507782), content assistant for JSTD in Eclipse Neon does not work properly. You can install Tern plugin for Eclipse, which supports javascript autocompletion. Instruction for this plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Eclipse-IDE). You can also downgrade Eclipse to Mars version, but it only supports older version of javascript.